Multiplicating rows but with different values in one column
I have excel file with products but they have many codes (last column).
It look like this:



PRODUCT
CODE
CODE 2
CODE 3




PRODUCT1
8005125781706
--------
--------


PRODUCT2
5907078127378
8595013626184
--------


PRODUCT3
5907690831561
5902188482423
5902557436293



What i need is codes in one column like this:



PRODUCT
CODE




PRODUCT1
8005125781706


PRODUCT2
5907078127378


PRODUCT2
8595013626184


PRODUCT3
5907690831561


PRODUCT3
5902188482423


PRODUCT3
5902557436293



I can do it manually but i have over 3000 products in this file.
Is there a way to do it automaticly?
